# Concatenating at start of string inside of loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which concatenates to the end of the string "errors":

```js
this.errors += `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] `;
this.errors += response.data.message;
this.errors += "\n-----------------\n\n";
```

Which generates the following string:

```
[30/12/2020 14:48:00] Error 1
-----------------

[30/12/2020 14:49:10] Error 2
-----------------
```

However I need to concatenate at the start of the string so the most recent error is always at the top:

```
[30/12/2020 14:49:10] Error 2
-----------------

[30/12/2020 14:48:00] Error 1
-----------------
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this::

```
const message = `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] ` 
  + response.data.message
  + "\n-----------------\n\n";
this.errors = message + this.errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.errors = "\n-----------------\n\n" + this.errors;
this.errors = response.data.message + this.errors;
this.errors = `[${new Date().toLocaleString()}] ` + this.errors;
```

Answer (score 0):

One could just utilize an array to store the errors.

```js
const errors = [];

function addError(message) {
  errors.unshift(`${new Date().toLocaleString()} ${message}`);
}

function displayErrors() {
  console.log(errors.join("\n-----------------\n\n"));
}

addError("Error 1");
addError("Error 2");
addError("Error 3");
displayErrors();
```